# MATLAB - Trouble with an integration approximation

Tags: matlab

I've been given a coding exercise to get me up to speed with MATLAB, but I'm having a bit of an issue getting out what I need.

I am trying to numerically integrate the Gaussian probability function on given intervals (variable bins). I am trying to do this by using the trapezoidal rule. I would expect the sum of all those integrals to be close to one, however what I'm getting in my results is getting smaller (for example, attaining a value of 0.5 when I set the variable bins to 100).

What I'm essentially doing is subdividing the x-axis into "bins", and taking the integral of a Gaussian PDF along the points contained within the bins. So, for example, say that I have the x-axis running from 0 to 19.9, incrementing by 0.1, so I have 200 "points". Now, say that I want to have ten bins. Then, each bin will contain 20 points, and I need to perform an integral approximation between every point in each bin.

Now, I've kind of got the following happening so far;

```
clear

%Sets location of the Gaussian PDF
s_1 = 5;
s_2 = 15;

%Sets the domain of the x-axis
x = [0:0.1:19.9];

%Sets the number of bins, and the size of each bin
b = 100;
points = numel(x);
binsize = (points)/b;

%Arranges all of the prescribed x-values into their necessary bins
t = reshape(x,binsize,b);

%Calculates p(r_n|s_n)
for i = 1:b
    r_s1(i) = trapz(t(:,i),normpdf(t(:,i),s_1));
    r_s2(i) = trapz(t(:,i),normpdf(t(:,i),s_2));
end
```

Now, for a small number of bins (say, 10), the approximation comes out quite nicely, and the sums of the elements of r_s1 and r_s2 both come out relatively close to 1 (as the integral of the Gaussian PDF should be 1). However, as I start bumping up the sizes of my bins, the value of this sum starts dropping. All things considered, I'd have expected it to stay around the same value.

Is this an error in my mathematical approach to the problem I've been posed, or have I messed up my code??

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use the Normal cumulative distribution function [normcdf](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html)? Also: You didn't really specify what you are actually trying to solve (the mathematics).

Comment: I don't really know what your actual question is, but in regards to why the values will get smaller: Integrating with the trapezoidal rule you will be quite likely overestimating the integral, as the areas where you are integrating are mostly convex parts of the function. So finer integration will give more accurate results. You should obviously not really get to `1` if you don't do integration from `-Inf` to `Inf` as the support of the GPDF is infinite. So basically your integration rule is overestimating and will become more accurate with finer bins.

Comment: I guess my question is really asking what I'm doing wrong, in a sense. Inputting that code with a bin size of 10 gives me a value of about 0.9. However, if increase the bin size to say, 100, I get a value closer to 0.5. My impression was that an increase in bins would lead to an increase in the accuracy of the approximation, or at the very least, not change it too dramatically. I feel like there's an error in what I've written to make the estimation drop so much.

Comment: Which value is `0.5`? To ask: What am I doing wrong, you must first explain what your goal is. I can't find it in your question.

Comment: The sum of all the elements of the r_s1 array. Same for r_s2.

Comment: Ahh, it's kind of difficult for me to express. What I'm trying to do is split each of the PDFs into sections, and calculate the area under the curve of each section. So I'm essentially just doing a trapezoidal approximation, with the size of each trapezoid being dependant on the number of bins. I'm then going on to do extra work on said probabilities, but I was under the impression that these probabilities should be summing to 1, or at least close to 1.

Comment: Then I may suggest to you to use as a first sentence something along those lines: *I am trying to numerically integrate the gaussian probability function on given intervals (according to the variable `bins`). I am trying to do this by using the trapezoidal rule. I would expect the sum of all those integrals to be close to one, however what I'm getting in my results is converging to 0.5 instead, if I make those bins finer*

Comment: I can't reproduce the value you are getting close to `0.5`. Please post the code that gets this result.

Comment: I placed all the above code in a script, executed the script, then within the command window, sum(r_s1), after setting b = 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bins` you are using don't partition the interval `[0, 19.9]`.
Looking at the variable `t`:

```
t = 
         0    0.2000    0.4000    0.6000    ...
    0.1000    0.3000    0.5000    0.7000    ...
```

You see that your first bin ends at `0.1`, but the second bin starts only at `0.2`, so in this case you are only integrating over half the interval, ergo the result `~0.5`.

The solution that changes the least of your code would probably be to add

```
t = [x(1), t(end,1:end-1); t];
```

After your `t = reshape(x,binsize,b);` reshape line.

Comment: Do you know of any way that I could partition the set to include all the gaps within the intervals?? Would I just set up something that would take the last value in one column and the first value in the proceeding column??

Comment: @Jack: I added a quick fix to your problem, but I guess you would be better off, if you represented the bins via the two values `bin(i,:) = [0, 0.1]` and then use `linspace(bin(i,1), bin(i,2), numberOfPointsYouWant)` instead.